# How to filter out a value that contains whitespace in Chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome, filter, google-chrome-extension, console

The string we need to filter out is: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: "sync" is not available in this instance of Chrome`

There's no single unique word we can target here for removal, nor is there a specific filename we can exclude. Entering any value with a space, like `-"in this instance of chrome"` or `-/in this instance of chrome/` leads to any and all logging messages from every source being filtered out. Can this be worked around without having to do something really ridiculous and unwieldy with regex?

Not exactly readable, but the only thing that seems to work is: `-/in\sthis\sinstance\sof\schrome/`

Comment: The `\s` or `\x20` regexp token is the only way. You can report the problem on https://crbug.com